# Load whole aspx page in page without postback

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have simple Default.aspx page:

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnPage1" runat="server" OnClientClick="return changePage(1);" Text="Click To Get Page1" />
        <br />

        <asp:Button ID="btnPage2" runat="server" Text="Click To Get Page2" />
        <br />


        <div id="dvPageBody">

        </div>
```

Also has two other pages page1.aspx and page2.aspx

I want to load page1.aspx or page2.aspx in div : dvPageBody of Default.aspx according to user clicks on button.

For that i written javascript function :

```
function changePage(pageName) {

            if (pageName == "1") {

                $("#dvPageBody").load("page1.aspx");

            }
            else
                $("#dvPageBody").load("page2.aspx");

            return false;
        }
```

But its not showing me any page in div.

What method should i follow???

Please help me.

**Edit1 :**

[image]

Comment: Please use jquery ajax

Comment: Make sure page paths are correct. Try with $("#dvPageBody").load("~/page2.aspx");

Comment: @malkam after these changes also not loading. Above i pasted image for path. plz help

Comment: Just debug n see whether control is going to if condition and check postback is happening or not?

Comment: @C.Ronaldo have you included or load the `jQuery` before you call `function changePage(pageName)`? I've tried it and it's working without problem. And just to make sure, did your `page1.aspx` and `page2.aspx` have a content or just empty?